# Python regex find everything inside curly brackets after a certain string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Hi so I'm struggling with regex a little bit. I have a rpt file from which I need to get specific data from. The File looks something a bit like this:

```
lots of text...
[MS]
{
;Mass   % BPI
238.85  0.943
247.64  0.984
378.65  0.990
...
}
lots of text...
```

I want to get everything inside the curly brackets after this string occurred: [MS]. The problem is there are many more curly brackets in this file and they are not only surrounding the data i need.

What I already tried is this:

```
import re

file = input("Enter file path: ")
if len(file) < 1:
    file = "path"
handle = open(file)

pattern = r'^([-0-9\.eE+]+)[ \t]*(;|,)?[ \t]*([-0-9\.eE+]*)$'
findings = re.findall(pattern, handle)

print(findings)

#and then making a single dict out of it with key-value pairs
```

But that doesn't give me all I need, it return some of the Values but not all of it.

In the end I want the Numbers inside curly brackets as a dictionary (example: Key: 238.85, Value: 0.943) so I can plot it afterwards.

note: The spaces between the Mass and BPI 'Columns' are Tabs.

Comment: Can there be any more `{` and `}` inside the block after `[MS]`?

Comment: No it closes again after that block without any inside it.

Comment: Are there more than one block, or is it always single/unique?

Comment: If you use [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you could probably use a [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) based regex [like this one](https://regex101.com/r/SneY4b/2). Can't put an answer right now.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew yes there are many of them

Comment: So, the result is a list of dictionaries, or a single dictionary with all the key-value pairs from all blocks?

Comment: A single dictionary with key-value pairs

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58519332/3832970) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract all blocks between `{` and `}` after `[MS]` and then extract all the necessary data from the block:

```
import re
results = []

with open(path_to_file, 'r') as r:
    for block in re.findall(r'\[MS\]\s*{([^{}]+)}', r.read()):
        results.extend(re.findall(r'^(\d[\d.]*)\t(\d[\d.]*)$', block, re.M))

print(dict(results))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QgYMft)

**Block matching regex**

- `\[MS\]` - a literal `[MS]` text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `{` - a `{` char
- `([^{}]+)` - Group 1 (this is what `re.findall` will return): any 1+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

**Number extraction regex**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M`)
- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Group 1 (key): a digit and then any 0+ digits or dots
- `\t` - a tab
- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Group 2 (value): a digit and then any 0+ digits or dots
- `$` - end of a line (due to `re.M`).

Comment: @bimarian Do you mean `\[MS\]` can be `[APPLE]`, etc.? Try `re.findall(r'\[{}\]\s*{{([^{{}}]+)}}'.format(re.escape(key)), r.read())`

Answer (score 1):

Do a multi-stage extracting process. The first stage is a regex that extracts the stuff between the brackets after MS:

```
re.search(r"\[MS\]\s*{([^}]+)}", s).group(0)
```

From there you can parse the data line by line.

Comment: If I use that it gives me a error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @bimarian That only means you are not passing the data as a single string to the `re` method. Show your whole relevant code in the question.

Comment: Ok will ad it in the question